# Compare open-endedness of two questions

Tags: support, questions, asking-questions, scope, off-topic

Could you tell me why one question is closed and the other is not?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687421/features-that-vim-lacks
[What is your most productive shortcut with Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218390/what-is-your-most-productive-shortcut-with-vim)

How can I ask "Which source-code-editing features vim lacks?"

What about this 924 questions? They should be deleted too? because of open-endedness or is it just a matter of tagging correctly the questions? https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/software-rec?sort=votes&pagesize=15

OK. I understand that you don't wish such questions here. Would it be possible to redirect users with such questions to this [web](http://listpod.net/about)? Or make a contract with the web and retag the questions with tag "open_minded" and migrate them to that web?

Comment: historical reasons? The former would be closed too if it was asked today?

Comment: Why do you want to close questions that are useful to people? Look at the votes of the second question which tells something about its usefulness.

Comment: Because we tried "useful to people" as a metric for a while, and it results in no bounds and no focus. The old question will likely be closed very soon (since you've brought attention to it), though it will likely never be deleted because it has a bjillion votes.

Comment: There are many such questions :-) with highest rating and I like them and people too. Why don't you just ignore it and focus on another question? There are questions that are dynamic and change with time. Or should I specify exactly the version of vim?

Comment: There are plenty of crappy questions on SO, but that doesn't give you an excuse to ask crappy questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now that you've gone and observed this, thus collapsing the wave function, they're both closed, the way they should be. Thanks for pointing those out - there are a lot of yet-unclosed questions which would, by all rights, deserve it.

In other words, those are oooold questions, asked back when the rules were different and dinosaurs roamed the earth (2009, in this case). Rules have changed since then (to prevent SO from drowning in a deluge of "what's your favorite X" and "hidden features of Y" lists-masqueraded-as-questions), so new questions like this are no longer accepted, and the old are temporarily tolerated, and slowly closed one by one.

(as for "Why don't you just ignore it and focus on another question?" - we tried. The result was a vast, endless sea of questions without a clear answer, just drifting along, overwhelming the people that could otherwise answer actual answerable questions. See, the number of questions or disk space or bandwith is not a real problem; it's the number of *people* who are capable *and* willing to answer.

Also, I *would* vote to close and then just ignore, but 1) others have already done that and 2) the people who post duplicate and off-topic questions (e.g. the OP of this question) keep bringing this up and making a fuss.)

Comment: (several quantum mechanics were harmed in the making of this answer)

Comment: If people know the best tools they are able to be more effective in answering questions, don't you think? I wouldn't close this type of questions, it's unique source of information and everybody could have a choice to filter this information out from his focus. You are wasting your time with censorship instead of doing something useful.

Comment: @xralf: You seem to have come in saying "oh, this is all completely wrong, you should run the site my way, it's much better" - that is unlikely to happen.1) Without community moderation,this site would swiftly degrade into a cespool of spam,rants,and non-questions. 2)The policies here weren't given from On High they are the result of vast discussion and experimentation over several years; you may not like some of their effects, but IMNSHO the system is pretty well balanced. 3) Finally,if this site's policies offend you, there are other Q&A sites that are unbounded by "programming-relatedness".

Answer (score 2):

> Features that vim lacks

- Not useful to VIM users, also not useful to users who don't use VIM

> What is your most productive shortcut with Vim?

- Useful to VIM users

Boths are off topic on Stack Overflow IMHO though.

Comment: How long my question exists? How long the other question exists? Which of them is more difficult to answer? Who is VIM-user? Who is non-Vim user? Is it good to close the eyes and be interested only in one editor (e.g. don't be interested in features other editors have)?

Comment: >>And the other question is Community Wiki, No rep farming can be done since then.<< I don't understand your sentense. I should ask it on some community wiki? What "rep farming" means?

Comment: Isn't it easier to just ignore it and give it another tag? e.g. open_ended?

Comment: Storage is cheaper and cheaper and such information can be stored somewhere where people can choose if they want to ignore it or not. Users could vote for some "critical tags" like open_ended, useless, annoying, argumentative (or below the question could be buttons (flags) with this functionality)

Comment: @xralf: Storage, bandwidth and other technical parameters are not interesting; what you're suggesting has been tried many moons ago, and failed (and those very tags that you have re-invented have been [eradicated from the site](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)). You see, *people* (the real scarce "resource" around here) were annoyed, complained en masse, rules have been changed. This is the result. (see e.g. this for background: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/ )

Answer (score 0):

I think it was closed because you were asking about the features users **liked** about vim. Liking is subjective and is personal opinion. If you asked the question the way you said "Which source-code-editing features vim lacks?" I do not think it will be closed.

Comment: Thank you for advice. I will edit it.