# Why were some historical non-constructive questions undeleted?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, policy, question-quality, broken-windows

I notice that [What is the single most influential book every programmer should read?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read) and [Strangest language feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature) have been undeleted by a Stack Exchange developer.

After long months of [framing these pieces of garbage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112910/do-not-lock-old-questions), the Stack Overflow community, with the help of moderators, had finally managed to [close those close-worthy questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26014/why-is-the-stack-overflow-community-so-aggressive-about-question-criteria) and delete them as part of a [cleanup of the worst upvoted garbage questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122120/the-great-question-deletion-audit-of-2012).

Does this represent a [sudden change](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/) to the principle that [real questions have answers](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/)? Or that [bad questions get closed then deleted](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/the-stack-overflow-question-lifecycle/)?

I must say that when I see this, my first reaction is ***Why should I bother cleaning up the trash when it gets shoved back into my face?*** Should I continue to vote to close and flag posts on Stack Overflow?

And my second reaction is to wonder whether I really want to participate on a site that thinks that [being able to write `10[a]` in C is strange](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1995156) (if you know C, it's not strange) and that [every single programmer must have read all of about 500 different books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read) including *[The Alchemist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Alchemist_%28novel%29)* and the [*Tao Te Ching*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tao_Te_Ching). ***As a programmer, do I even want to be associated with Stack Overflow?*** If I show my SO activity on my CV, will this brand me as a second-rate programmer — meaning that [Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) is targeted at second-rate programmers?

What is the change in policy that now justifies having these questions on the site? Does it affect only Stack Overflow or other Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: I thought 10[a] was indeed quite strange, and no, I'm not a C developer.  Can't you just let the rest of us have a little fun reading this old material without getting so angry?

Comment: Also, to avoid burning your eyes with these awful, awful fun questions, I would recommend you stick with the "Newest Questions" feed on your favorite tag.  Any silliness showing up there will be closed post haste, so hopefully that will keep your anger down :)

Comment: @AdamRackis Read it on [Stack Printer](http://stackprinter.com/). There's a lot of stuff I find strange in various languages. What I find strange is probably not what you find strange. And that is exactly why this is not a good question for Stack Exchange. It should be your blog post, with your list of strange features; and my blog post, with my list of strange features, and so on.

Comment: I honestly never thought it was possible for software engineers to get so worked up over rule-following until I saw the rage over old content here.  I always thought I was a member of the coolest, most laid-back career field on earth.  Apparently not.  My deepest sympathy that silly questions like this evoke such anger from you.

Comment: If it's so good, why do the people fighting for it to stay on SO not also host their own CC compliant version? Or does the stank stain too much to attach their own domain to? @ada

Comment: @random - that's a bit silly, isn't it?  Pekka had talked about hosting this stuff himself, then said how much work it'd be and that he couldn't (leading to the archive post).  I work a regular job, consult, teach, and have a wife and kid.  Telling me or any other engineer to just scrape this stuff and host it is absurd.

Comment: The getting "shoved back in my face" comment seems really over the top.

Comment: No one said to rehost the entire swathe of deleted crap. Just the small few that apparently are so golden they need to linger on SO like jock itch. Users keep coming back with all the time in the world in how good these certain few are but have a dearth of it when it comes to rehosting @ada

Comment: Also, the implication that potential employers care about this sort of post seems excessively rhetorical.  How is this any different from, say, http://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/gnu-overflow.html ?

Comment: @JonEricson Compare these two URLS — I've highlighted the important parts for you: gnu.org/ **fun/jokes** /gnu-overflow.html ; stackoverflow.com/questions? **sort=votes** .

Comment: @Gilles: So... programmers aren't supposed to like jokes or fun?  Or just us "second-rate" programmers do?  (And do we really ask potential employers to look at the most popular questions on the site or do we ask them to look at _our own_ best questions?)

Comment: @JonEricson I hope programmers are allowed to like jokes and fun, because I'm a programmer and I like jokes and fun. But when my boss asks me what I've done this week, if I show him programmer cartoons, he is not going to be amused. There's a time and place for everything. [so] is for programming, not for jokes about programming. (How is this relevant anyway? We're not talking about joke posts here.)

Comment: @Gilles - are those really our only two choices?  Wipe these questions from the site, or spend 40 hours a week reading them?  I certainly hope we engineers are allowed an intelligent middle ground whereby they exist for a fun diversion every once in a while.

Comment: Seriously, what the hell? First we get a bunch of people whining that questions were deleted. Now, once we've come around to a better solution (leaving the posts as they be, but locking them and adding a notice of historical significance), we get people bitching that they were undeleted? What is going to make you people happy? **Some people like these questions, and they should be able to stay put just for that reason alone. If you don't like them, you don't have to look at them.** They're not hurting your Internet by being there, and they're making other people's Internet better. The end.

Comment: *"my second reaction is to wonder whether I really want to participate on a site that thinks that being able to write `10[a]` in C is strange"* And that makes me wonder if I want to participate on a site where users are so damn arrogant that they can't imagine someone wouldn't know every nuance of the syntax of a language. As you mention, it might not be strange to people who know C well, but not everyone has to know C well to ask a C question. That's the whole point of a programming Q&A site. **If everyone knew everything well, they wouldn't have to ask any questions.** Get over yourself.

Comment: Sigh.  I brought up the '“GNU's Not Unix” stack overflow bug' joke because I had a boss (many years ago, of course) who thought open source was frivolous because of it (and for other reasons).  If you aren't posting cartoons, what does an employer care if someone else does?  The point is bringing in FUD like "If I show my SO activity on my CV, will this brand me as a second-rate programmer?" weakens the argument.  The fact is, you can only control what you, yourself do.

Comment: “Some people like these questions, and they should be able to stay put just for that reason alone.” Then we should never close any question. The asker liked them, so they should be able to stay put. If you want those questions to stay on the Internet, **get off your bum and save them somewhere**.

Comment: @AdamRackis So propose something different. Maybe we should have a threshold above which posts are not deleted, changing moderation from quality to popularity. I know, we could call it Reddit.

Comment: @Gilles - there you go with your straw man arguments again.  I'm quite confident old, extremely popular posts can be kept without the site devolving into Reddit.  The real question is why this annoys you so much.  Do you have some sort of OCD that makes you crazy knowing these questions exist, breaking current quality standards?  Are you just an unhappy person?  Are software developers in Paris not overpaid and under-worked like we are in America?  Just lighten the hell up, dude.

Comment: +1 to @AdamRackis, and not just because he has a great first name. This is an incredibly inane argument...is it really hurting you? Can you really not live without a rigorous metric for distinguishing old and relevant (but not necessarily something we'd want as *new*) content from content that really is garbage? If we could come up with a specific set of exceptionless rules to define these things, we could moderate the site with software. We use humans so that they can employ judgement, as these things are *subjective*.

Comment: @Adam (and Adam): “these things are subjective, therefore I am right”. My counter-argument: these things are subjective, therefore I am right. That's not going to move things along.

Comment: My assertion (and I think you know this) is that these things are subjective, and therefore an attempt at establishing a rigid standard for what *must* stay or what *must* be deleted is pointless. Your assertion seems to be that there *is* such a standard and these questions do not meet it. Your argument appears to go against the very idea that these judgments are subjective.

Comment: @AdamRobinson Of course there is a standard, and of course its application is subjective. In your opinion, these questions fall on the side of inclusion. In my opinion, these questions fall on the side of deletion. It's a difference in opinion, we're both making subjective judgements.

Comment: @Gilles Nobody doubts that these old (popular) questions violate current standards.  The point is, letting them stay locked with an historical banner does no harm to you.  It does not prevent you from asking or answering new questions.  I don't know if you suffer from OCD and really *really* need the site organized **perfectly**, or if you're just an angry person, but deleting these questions serves no rational purpose.  ***MOVE ON***

Comment: why don't you just stick to Unix and Linux for good? you will find more joy there and probably can enjoy a few more years of life. now whenever I see a reference to some deleted question that seems interesting to me, I am reminded of just the right person to curse for my inconvenience.

Comment: There is no need to personally attack another user when they are discussing site policy and clean up. Making threats on another user's life is also expressly forbidden @pru

Comment: @random this is not a threat on his life, just the adage that angry people don't live long

Comment: If he is angry enough to take his personal crusade this far, why can't a second-rate programmer be angry enough to ask him to get lost?

Comment: We are debating the merits of the content on the site. Not where someone lives, what language they speak, or how angry they are or whatever else is going on in their lives. @pru

Comment: There was a time when we had no difficulty arguing about this without telling people to lighten the hell up, or saying they have OCD, or they need to buy some Prozac, or that they must have miserable lives, or that they need to get off the site and go somewhere else. The last week on meta has been a series of the rudest comments I've ever seen on Stack Exchange, one after the other. I'm not sure if it's depressing, infuriating, or just embarassing

Comment: @MichaelM - with the greatest possible respect, one side is saying that old content from SO's early history, which a lot of people like, should be kept and locked with an historical significance banner.  The other side claims that this content is "trash", that people will spend 40 hours at their jobs reading it (to the consternation of their boss), that the other side "can't control themselves", and is turning SO into Reddit.  You can't expect to make arguments like that and not have your mental state questioned.

Comment: @AdamRackis If you can't comprehend how the other side of a debate could think the way they do other than that they're just mentally unstable, you should probably stop arguing. We're not insane, or depressed, or angry -- we're just tired of dealing with this argument again and again. Saying that questions that don't fit SO's structure well should be deleted is far from insane. Everyone seems to agree that those same questions asked today would rightly be closed -- but people who want to close old versions of the same question are insane?

Comment: @AdamRackis I have claimed that some of this content is trash (specifically, here, two questions, though they're not the only ones). The rest is fabrication from your part. Furthermore, the last three comments from you have contained some form of personal attack against me; if you can't help making such attacks, do not post at all.

Comment: @Gilles - most of the quotes from my last comment were not from you, but from other equally strident people making similar arguments, though you did imply that the existence of this old and popular content would lead people to spend 40 hours (which is a standard workweek in America, not sure if France still has the legally mandated 35 hour thing) `But when my boss asks me what I've done this week, if I show him programmer cartoons, he is not going to be amused.`

Comment: As to personal attacks, that's not appropriate, but you can't expect to keep making strident, angry calls to delete popular content over and over and over again without people getting sick of it, and lashing out.  As many, many others have mentioned, this content is not affecting you, or preventing you from asking or answering questions.  In fact, you have to know where this stuff is and actively to it in order to see it. To flip out over this content that's over in the corner of SO does in all honesty betoken a certain degree of misanthropy / OCD. That's just my observation.  @Mich

Comment: @Adam: You also can't expect that angry calls to have old crap content polluting the site won't make people angry as well. Just because something is popular doesn't mean it's valuable or a good question for SO. If you go by "popular" you just have a site full of "Best programming chair", "Best music (for a programmer)" and other bikeshed questions like that.

Comment: Also note that this idea that that those question have been generally accepted as appropriate back when they were posted is just not true. For example just look at the revision history of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature and you'll see that it was heavily controversial when it was posted. Some people just liked their rep-farming bikesheds while others thought they polluted SO.

Comment: Although the way in which this question was written may have been over-the-top, the underlying issue is a completely legitimate one. Moderators are elected by the community, developers are not. Why are a tiny group of "admins" unilaterally overriding the decisions made by several members of the community and the moderators whom they elected?

Comment: @Aarobot History is littered with tyrannical leaders who were "elected by the community."  The answers to the question about the deletion http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122120/the-great-question-deletion-audit-of-2012 show many things, but not a consensus for deletion.

Comment: @JohnMcG: One question had 15 delete votes before a moderator stepped in. Pointing to a meta question where a relatively small number (compared to the number of question views) of anonymous voters upvoted a few posts full of empty rhetoric regarding questions *which are not even currently under discussion* does nothing to substantiate what appears to be your position on the subject.

Comment: @JohnMcG At the time the answers were deleted, [my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/122127) was one of the top answers, definitely above [bobobobo's non-answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/122133/149076). The voting trend reversed *after* the moderator's action, which followed what looked at the time like the majority opinion.

Comment: @Aarobot Gilles This post has been cited by the moderators as evidence of community consensus, when it shows anything but.  My point is that the actions do not seem to be respecting the opinion of the community, which your efforts to disqualify input confirms.  "Anonymous voters" -- as if the anonymity is cowardly rather than a constraint of the system.
Exactly what would be a valid way to register dissent from this if using the voting mechanism of the site is somehow illegitimate?

Comment: @JohnMcG: You're all over the place. These *specific* questions that are being asked about reflected a widespread agreement at the time between both trusted/high-activity community members and moderators. They were overturned by developers without *any discussion or warning whatsoever*. It's *possible* that there was even *larger* group at the outset who wanted to preserve them, but if they didn't weigh in at the time, that's not evidence of "[not] respecting the opinion of the community", and the mere *possibility* is not a valid reason for devs to publicly overturn moderator decisions.

Comment: IMO the appropriate thing to do would have been to ping the SO mods into the Teacher's Lounge and say "look, we know you hate these, but blah blah blah and we need them to stay, so please start undeleting & locking these with post notices". It's not appropriate behaviour to just slap mods in the face with a "STFU, we know better". Moderators are *always* expected to be able to justify their actions when challenged on meta; do developers not have the same responsibility, simply because they are devs? Mods are unpaid volunteers, they may not code but they have way more *moderation* experience.

Comment: @JohnMcG Again: a moderator asked on meta whether to delete some questions. After a few days, there was a majority opinion (as reflected by voting on the answers on meta) to delete these questions and the meta discussion had died down, so moderators deleted them. *Later* the meta discussion came back alive and the majority opinion changed. **The moderators did exactly what the community told them**. The opinion reversal happened *after* my post here.

Comment: It seems we have 2 possibilities: 1.) The current voting and answers are not representative of what things looked like after the change. or 2.) It is representative.  If 2, then we have a case of moderators going against the will of the commmunity. But Gilles and @Aarobot say it's #1.  Ok...

Comment: If that's the case, then it seems apparent that the original question did not generate input from stakeholders. I suppose Gilles and @Aarobot would say that's too bad for them, or that their subsequent activity on that thread is somehow illegitimate -- because it's anonymous, because it's empty rhetoric, etc.

Comment: As far as your relationship with the SE devs go, that's your problem, and I'm not going to referee that dispute. What I don't care for is this notion that your actions should be above reproach because you were merely exercising the community's desires, when it seems pretty apparent now that this is not the case.

Comment: @JohnMcG: It's not what "we say", it's what actually happened. You can see it for yourself in [bobobobo's rep history](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/111307/bobobobo?tab=reputation). There were a ton of *recent* upvotes that massively skew the rankings.

Comment: @Aarobot I will stipulate that there exists a time t such that votes(Gilles's responses(t)) > votes(bobobobo's response(t)).
I don't see that that demonstrates a community consensus for deletion.

Comment: @JohnMcG: It's easy to say that when you have the benefit of hindsight, but consider that (a) this issue would probably never have come up at all were it not for the recent rep changes, and (b) one of the questions had 15 deletion *votes* on it, and it's extremely rare for any question to get that many delete votes. Seriously, that's huge; most of the time, deletion momentum peters out after 5 or 6 votes. A lot of VIPs *really* wanted that question gone - possibly because there is a *constant* stream of copycat book-rec questions, not just on Stack Overflow but on every other Stack Exchange.

Comment: @JohnMcG Why do you insist on a consensus for deletion? There was a *majority* for deletion, no consensus. When the community is divided, it is up to moderators to evaluate the arguments and take a decision. It would only have been *wrong* for moderators to delete the question if there had been a strong majority to keep the question.

Comment: To me, it's a requirement if you're going to claim that you were acting in the name of the community rather than your own vision.  In this post, you are implying that your actions are supported by the community, while the SE employees' were not, and thus yours are more legitimate.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Self-serve second rounds, otherwise known as vomiting up your lunch or slight acid reflux, can only be a good thing. It shows us where we've been and how much things will not change or improve despite a community waking up and coming to its senses as it rolls over and smells the funk wafting in their face, ears beholden to the sound of thighs.

Do these Lazarus questions make the Internet a better place? By no longer being broken links from the Stack Exchange blog, they must surely do. Since when is linkrot of any kind useful? This is Pendleton reaching through the streams of time to communicate with Jesus that will forever validate its existence.

Stack Overflow is not some kind of Yahoo! where they float or bring up content and then sunset them when they no longer fit with the community sense. They hold tight and muchly to these; close to the breast and free from the waves of the ocean.

Can you spend countless hours reading through these lists and see the corner of your mouth turn up in a wry sense, drooling with mirth of times gone by? That's the best kind of quality indicator there is.

"List of book covers", "Hidden features of X" and "Strangest language feature" are now what you would call the fresh point of call for those to RTFM as to why a certain programming quirk is the way it is or does as it says it doesn't or how a hookah can help you refactor code like a snicker-snack.

As the 8-track repeats for us all, because there is no better place to host these, not even some curated blog or archive space, they must belong on Stack Overflow by way of default. You can try and flush it all you want, but that history is backing up on you with a megaton spin and no plunger is ever going to know victory.

Comment: The only thing worse than deleting fun questions is hyperbole.

Comment: Looks like someone is having a little too much fun with the vote button... lol

Comment: I can't tell whether this is for or against.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I read this as “someone was wrong on the Internet, but don't let this bother you”.

Comment: your attitude for preventing link rot certainly fits the [mission of making Internet better](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/stack-overflow-gives-back-2010/) but how much damage would it do to SO if it is followed **consistently**, by undeletion of many other popular questions? In that sense, I would prefer a ["redirect" approach suggested recently by Jeremy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/122207/165773) as it would make much less harm to SO Q&A quality

Comment: @gnat Once again, I fully support archiving deleted content elsewhere and redirecting to it. I'm not motivated enough to set it up, but surely you'd think some of the anti-deletion people would be.

Comment: @Gilles: I'd say that you've accurately articulated the attitude of most, if not all, of the inclusionists (including the part about not being motivated enough).

Comment: @Gilles, as you maybe noticed I personally am rather strong deletioninst, but the issue of link rot seem to be turning me the other way around. Link rot hurt me in the past, essentially making me leave [another programming community](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109383/was-it-a-mistake-to-flag-these-answers#comment282698_109383) and it's quite sad to see that the story seem to be repeating at SO

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm a deletionist. For me, plain deletion > motivation threshold > save the content. It seems that for every inclusionist, whine on meta > motivation threshold > save the content.

Answer (score 50):

I'm getting really tired of the "framing garbage" argument that you keep throwing out.  I've personally deleted over 38,000 posts on Stack Overflow, so I already know what to do with garbage, thank you very much.  The discussion that we're having is about what to do with *good content* that doesn't fit perfectly within the guidelines of the FAQ, not garbage.  If you don't understand the difference, then please stay out of the discussion.

Comment: A banana peel is trash. A 50-year old jalopy that drips oil all over the place is also trash. Maybe it belongs in a museum — so put it there, don't leave it blocking the street.

Comment: @Gilles To borrow your analogy, the car is **locked** in the garage and you're complaining about it blocking the street.  Traffic isn't being blocked here.  Questions are still being answered the same as always.

Comment: __"If you don't understand the difference, then please stay out of the discussion."__ I am delighted to hear that from one of the old farts. Thank you, Bill, you just make me regain [some hope about meta](https://twitter.com/#!/jaredpar/status/175675699422707712). Maybe there is, after all, some sane users left here in the madhouse? A heartfelt `+1` from me. What's been happening here recently is [seriously hurting SO](https://twitter.com/#!/MalwareMinigun/status/175815813587140608).

Comment: @sbi - it turns out there's a class of uptight software developers who just have to rules enforced perfectly, with no exceptions, or they throw a fit.  I honestly always associated abject rule following to minimum-wage grunt workers.  I never knew (otherwise intelligent) knowledge workers were capable of such absurdity.  (btw, I loved your post on the C++ books question)

Answer (score 32):

Deleting useful content is not a good thing, especially when that useful content has thousands of links to it.

Dogma is one thing, but overall: Don't break the internet.

We ask people to post blurbs from linked answers so that if the link fails we still have the content, yet what you're proposing would make us as bad as those we're trying to overcome.

If a question has useful information, it should be locked, and a historical blurb should be placed at the head.  That way we won't break the internet, and we can still let people know that questions like that are not tolerated any longer.

There are a good number of questions that do not contain useful programming content, and [should be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508110/why-is-this-program-erroneously-rejected-by-three-c-compilers).

Also: Just because you wrote a meta post saying we should delete old content, doesn't mean that was the position adopted by the community or by the moderators.  It's a little disingenuous to act as if you've been betrayed by the community when there isn't any community consensus around these questions.

Answer (score 12):

The referenced posts were *undeleted and locked by an SE employee.*  That is their prerogative.

The pecking order goes like this:

```
Low-rep users --> High-rep users --> Moderators --> SE Staff
```

Think of the SE Staff as the Supreme Court.  They are the final word. Note that reversals of this kind (made by SE employees) are *exceptionally rare.*

As to *why* the decision was made to undelete these posts, it would appear that, in SE's judgement, *the value of their content* outweighs their negative characteristics.

Comment: _Note that reversals of this kind are exceptionally rare..._ must've been due to a dip in adsense because of @casperOne.

Comment: This answer seems wildly useless. "They were undeleted because SE employees are better than you". Obviously they can undelete whatever they want -- the question is *why* they undeleted it

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: You didn't see the last sentence in my answer?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I saw. It's conspicuously missing any explanation of what “the value of their content” may be.

Comment: @Gilles: You would have to ask the person who undeleted the question about that specifically.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I did.

Comment: @Gilles: And... what... did... he... say?

Comment: @RobertHarvey And… what… makes… you… assume… that… he… has… replied?

Comment: Just to hopefully derail this into another meme's area... I notice your hierarchy conspicuously is missing The Skeet.

Comment: @Andrew - Jon Skeet is not a level in the hierarchy; Jon Skeet **is** the hierarchy.

Comment: This explains *how* it was done (which we already know) but not *why* it was done (which the question asked), and especially *why it was done in this particular fashion, without warning or discussion* - although maybe they warned you privately, I don't know.

Comment: @Aarobot: Read the last sentence in my answer. Nobody was warned privately AFAIK, and they didn't discuss it with the mods first, which is fine with me; I rarely discuss my moderator decisions with the community unless they bring them up on meta. Note that the "Single Most Influential Book" question had delete votes cast against it by *15 community members,* which qualifies it for deletion under the new rules anyway. The SE team still has the final say.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: After having read/listened to what little the SE employees have had to say about it (including the recent "podcast"), it's not apparent to me at all that this was in fact the reason. I heard several statements around (a) inbound links, (b) votes and (c) page views, but little if anything substantive about the *value of their content*.

Comment: @Aarobot: That's the **only** reason why a "Not Constructive" post would get resurrected. Nobody disagrees that these questions are out of scope for the site. The only discussion has ever been around whether their intrinsic value to the community outweighs their off-topic-ness.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: You'd think so, but in Joel's own words, the fact that people *like* it is apparently sufficient justification. Unless he's implying that anything that's liked has value, but that extension is pretty easy to disprove.

Comment: @Aarobot: Ultimately, I think it's best that the community is allowed to make these decisions, not the moderators. The new delete rules are an attempt to balance this process, so that the moderators can stay out of the business of being proxies for people who want to decide the fate of these questions with a single moderator flag.

Answer (score 10):

I think the reason this post has attracted such angry responses—from me and others—is because it seems to suggest that the existence of these old, popular questions is a personal affront to you.  That un-deleting these posts constitutes throwing "trash in your face"

Instead of seeming so offended by these posts, can you instead point out actual, concrete problems that these posts present to the site?  The posts are locked, so they can't be edited and bumped; new, silly answers can't be added, which would also bump them.  They can't even be voted on.

The only *possible* problem is that they would create broken windows: people would see these posts, and think similar ones could be written today.  But of course there's an historical banner intended to disabuse people of this notion.  Naturally though there's nothing stopping people from ignoring the banner, or just not seeing it (it really should be more prominent, for what it's worth).

So with that I can only ask the following: is there any evidence that these old posts create broken windows?  Can you show us floods of Meta posts from users whining that their new list question got closed, while *that list question over there* exists?  I'm on meta more often than I probably should be, and I honestly have never seen a post complaining about a closed question *with the justification that the "weirdest programming language exists", so my question should too.*

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2Bwhy%20%2Bclosed

Comment: Also, http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/ Read [Mark Trapp's comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124439/community-led-deletionism-a-protocol-for-sanity/124455#comment333570_124461) (he was a moderator on Programmers, which has an even worse problem than SO with old content).

Comment: @Gilles - I read Mark's sweeping statement that leaving these questions locked "cheapens" other content, and he's entitled to his opinion.  But I have yet to see actual meta posts from users saying "Hey, junk list programming question is (locked) over there, so why in the world did my new list question get closed".  Does your meta search page have any examples?  I abortively tried the first two links, then got tired of it. It seems the people opposed to locking these questions are long on ideology, and short on facts.

Comment: @Gilles - if this really is about making Stack Overflow better, and not just about dogma, then why not support some combination of [my](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124492/improve-the-historical-significance-banner) or [Pekka's](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124464/show-battled-deleted-questions-to-the-public-as-if-they-were-10k-users) proposals to help keep these questions around, while minimizing any *possible* effect they could have as broken windows.  Doing that should make all rational parties happy.

Comment: Amazingly the Meta.Prog.SE front page is almost free of historical baggage today. But consider that just [Why … closed?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Bwhy+%2Bclosed) find 167 questions, most of are complaining about closures and would be avoided if there weren't hundreds of similar questions still on the site. Or look at gems like [What can we do about incorrectly pedantic moderation?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/3248) , where the FAQ doesn't deter from copycat questions.

Comment: “Why not support … Pekka's proposal” Oh, you've changed from insults to slander. [I did voice my support for his proposal.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124469)

Comment: @Gilles - my goodness.  You've been quite insulting yourself.  I find being accused of turning SO into reddit to be quite insulting, though I'm glad to hear you more or less support Pekka's post.  What I'm most interested in, though, is where the specific meta posts are demonstrating how much these posts are broken windows.  I'm a sucker for science, and I like to think about things in terms of testable predictions.  That these posts are broken windows should predict lots of meta posts from angry people wanting to ask X because [some stupid list question] exists over there.

Comment: On the topic of why such questions hurt the site, you might want to read [this](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3242/no-more-chairman-mao-reincarnate/3246#3246).

Comment: @Gilles - I'm quite happy Mark closed crap on PSE and helped improve the site's quality.  Good for him.  Now can you please show me all the Meta posts demonstrating why having these old popular questions locked and accessible on **STACK OVERFLOW** encourages the asking of similar questions?  No more rhetoric, just facts.

Comment: @AdamRackis: Oh, let's see here... [New "Hidden Features" questions...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52456) [Python Persecution?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57596) [Hidden-features question closed...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56079) [Why is my community wiki topic closed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58380) [...zero place for poll questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76483) [Why are some subjective questions open while others aren't?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40511/141911), [Compare open-endedness](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87640/141911)... need I go on?

Comment: Srsly, meta is *filled* with this "it's not fair that I can't do it too" whining, and that's just the whining that *hasn't been deleted yet!*

Comment: @Aarobot - Most of your links deal with questions that were open at the time.  I was rather unclear in my original question, but I edited it a bit above.  Popular poll questions **should not** be open, **should not** be on the top questions lists, etc.  They *do* create broken windows.  My point is that locking them with an historic banner and de-listed them should eliminate the broken windows problem

Comment: @AdamRackis: De-listing/de-searching is the key point - that is currently not being done. The post notice itself seems wildly ineffective, which isn't surprising considering that it appears at the bottom and we are, as a rule, talking about people who don't bother to read that far before spewing. I'm all in favour of making these available as historical artifacts to people who are specifically looking for them, but until we stop *advertising* the questions by listing them in the top 10, we are, effectively, throwing trash in people's faces. Locked or not.

Comment: @Aarobot - good news - it looks like these locked posts *are* being [de-listed](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/)  -- last bullet - "last but not least"

Comment: Yes, I noticed that very recently. It will be interesting to see how the various factions react.